# strftime giving wrong month name (February only...)

Tags: php, date, hebrew, strftime, setlocale

I have the following code, to get the month name of a certain date, and then using to get the name of the month in Hebrew.

```
$thismonthname = date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $thismonthnumber, 10)); 

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tel_Aviv');     // Set timezone to Israel   

$locale = 'he_IL.utf8'; setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale); // Set Locale to Hebrew

$thismonthnameheb = strftime('%B', strtotime($thismonthname));
```

It works perfectly, except for February.

When I print out $thismonthname it says "February" but when I print out $thismonthnameheb it says מרץ (march) in Hebrew.

Going crazy, I can't figure this out.

Comment: You're losing all "time" sense in there, since you're only passing around a month name.Your timezone conversion from UTC-0 -> UTC+2 will also be throwing stuff off. I'll bet that if you do `echo date('r', strtotime($thismonthname))` you'll get a full-blown date/time in March, exactly as PHP is doing with strftime()

Comment: which version you re using ? https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=27789

Answer (score 1):

You're doing too much conversion from time to string and back.
Instead of converting `time -> string -> time`, simply keep the time value and base the results on that:

```
$thismonthtime = mktime(0, 0, 0, $thismonthnumber, 10);
$thismonthname = date("F", $thismonthtime); 

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tel_Aviv');     // Set timezone to Israel   
$locale = 'he_IL.utf8'; setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale); // Set Locale to Hebrew

$thismonthnameheb = strftime('%B', $thismonthtime);
```

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with Hebrew, since, at least on the particular version of PHP I am using (5.3.10),

```
echo strftime('%d %B', strtotime('February'));
```

gives

```
01 March
```

As suggested in the comments, this arguably unexpected behaviour is due, basically, to PHP's assumption that **the day of a given month is the 30th unless the user actually specified a different value**.  Hence for February we overflow to the 1st of March.

A look at [this reference](http://derickrethans.nl/obtaining-the-next-month-in-php.html) might prove useful.

Answer (score 0):

Note the sequence:

```
php > $time = mktime(0,0,0,2, 10);
php > echo date('r', $time);
Mon, 10 Feb 2014 00:00:00 -0600  // everything ok here, I'm in UTC-6
php > date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tel_Aviv');
php > echo date('r', $time);
Mon, 10 Feb 2014 08:00:00 +0200  // note how it's now 8 hours "later"
php > $month =  date('F', $time);
php > echo $month;
February
php > $newtime = strtotime($month);
php > echo date('r', $newtime);
Sat, 01 Mar 2014 00:00:00 +0200  // hey! it's march again!
```

You screwed up by stripping your date down to a simple month name, then expecting PHP to magically be able to guess what you're expecting to do. If you feed it just a month, it's free to pick whatever it wants for the year/day/time values.